# Get string value of the GridView cell on click

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I have DataGrid that shows some values from MySQL database. I need that if I click on any column, the value will be saved to string. Is it even possible?

Here´s the code that shows mysql table in the datagrid

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Jméno from info", conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
    dataGridCustomers.DataContext = ds;
}
catch 
{
    WarnWindow vv1 = new WarnWindow(1);
    vv1.ShowDialog();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

[image: DataGrid Screenshot]

But if I click on (for example) Bohumil Homola, this value shall be saved as:

```
string name = Bohumil Homola (column value);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "save to string"? and can we see some sample code??

Comment: I have fixed few typos and made minor stylistic changes of your question. I have reindented your code so that it looks more ordered. And I have also modified your title to (as I think) better reflect your goal, and removed "C# WPF" from it, because it is a common consensus that if tags are set correctly they are not required in the title. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it. Here´s the code which I used:

```
DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)datagridname
    .ItemContainerGenerator
    .ContainerFromIndex(datagridname.SelectedIndex);
DataGridCell RowColumn = datagridname.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row).Parent as DataGridCell;
string ContentOfCell = ((TextBlock)RowColumn.Content).Text;
```